# 'Where' condition on the combination of multiple columns for a rule

Tags: postgresql, rules

I'm new to postgres.I need to create Rule on one of my table in postgres. I'm using postgres 11.4.

Here, is the syntax i'm using for this:

```
      CREATE RULE flagrule AS ON insert TO ms
  WHERE NEW.a = OLD.a and new.b = old.b and new.c = old.c and
new.d = old.d and new.e = old.e

DO instead
update ms set flag = 0  where 
a = NEW.a and
b= new.b and
c = new.c and
d = new.d and
e = new.e;
```

and getting below error:

```
     SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for 
   table "old"
    Hint: There is an entry for table "old", but it cannot be referenced 
      from this part of the query.
     Position: 76
```

I google about this a lot, but I got example only with single column condition in 'where' clause. If any one has any idea about this  then please let me know. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just a little question before going further : why are you not using a trigger?

Comment: trying with rule

Comment: Triggers are recommended over rules.

Comment: I think you should take a look on this part of the documentation as well : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-triggers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrule.html) states:

> Within `condition` and `command`, the special table names `NEW` and `OLD` can be used to refer to values in the referenced table. `NEW` is valid in `ON INSERT` and `ON UPDATE` rules to refer to the new row being inserted or updated. `OLD` is valid in `ON UPDATE` and `ON DELETE` rules to refer to the existing row being updated or deleted.

Since you are trying to create an `ON INSERT` rule, you cannot use `OLD`. What should that mean anyway?